# Error intsalling tensorflow via pip install

Tags: tensorflow, installation, pip

WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:\python38\Scripts\chardetect.exe' -> 'c:\python38\Scripts\chardetect.exe.deleteme'

I was trying to install Tensorflow via command pip install tensorflow. and after downloading everything at the end found this error..can anyone tell me why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.codegrepper.com/ you can use these two:

In Windows

```
python -m pip install -U pip --user
```

In Linux

```
pip install -U pip --user
```